# Filter MongoDB document's deep fields using Logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-filter

I am trying to rename some deep fields from my MongoDB document before uploading them to Elastic using Logstash.

For example: my MongoDB document looks like this:

```
name: "firstDoc",
infoArray: 
[
   {infoName: "i", elements:{e1: "e1", e2: "e2"}}, 
   {infoName: "j", elements:{e3: "e3", e4: "e4"}}
]
```

I was able to access the "name" field in logstash like this:

```
mutate { add_field => {"[otherDoc][name]" => "%{[document][name]}"} }
```

But I am not able to access the fields in infoArray, I have tried the rename:

```
mutate { rename => {"[document][infoArray][elements][e1]" => "[otherDoc][e1]"} }
```

I have also tried by adding it as a new field:

```
mutate { add_field => {"[otherDoc][e1]" => "%{[document][infoArray][elements][e1]}"} }
```

But still not working.

Is there any way to access deep fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, as follows:

```
mutate { rename => {"[document][infoArray][0][elements][e1]" => "[otherDoc][e1]"} }
```

or

```
mutate { add_field => {"[otherDoc][e1]" => "%{[document][infoArray][0][elements][e1]}"} }
```

**The index of infoArray should be specified in Logstash.**